# Why React-bootstrap Image doesn't load from reletive path?

Tags: image, reactjs, react-bootstrap

I'm learning React and I'm using React-bootstrap for style. 
I'm not sure why my react-bootstrap Image doesn't load the image with relative path. I tested with an absolute path for testing purpose with a random image from online, it works, but it doesn't work with relative path. Anybody knows how to fix that? 
Here is my code:

```
import {Grid, Row, Col, Image} from 'react-bootstrap';

<Row className="show-grid">
     <Col xs={11} sm={5}>
        <h5>Image</h5>
        <Image src="./src/assets/tech_digram_2.jpg" responsive />
        <Image src="./assets/person_profile_1.jpeg" responsive />
        <Image src="https://static.pexels.com/photos/296886/pexels-photo-296886.jpeg" responsive />
     </Col>
</Row>
```

#### Files/Directories structure

[image]

Answer (score 2):

Move your `assets` folder into your `public` directory.

I'm assuming you're using create-react-app. When webpack builds your app, it uses the publicPath to determine where your files will be served from. By default in create-react-app, it is setup to be served from your `public` directory. So, your app only has access to the files under the `public` directory once it gets built. Moving your assets into `public` should fix the issue.

Comment: @JampaThinlayTsarong No problem, if you can accept this as the correct answer that would be great!